# Python- Why are newlines "\n" being created when I don't want them to?

Tags: python, newline

I am writing strings to a text document using python 2.7

I am not adding then "\n" newline character until the very end of each line, yet when I open up the text document, newlines are being created on their own.
What am I doing wrong?

My code looks like this:

```
w.write(ID + "    " + Name + "    " + x + "     " + y + " " + "\n")
w.write(ID2 + "    " + Name2 + "    " + x2 + "     " + y2 + " " + "\n")
```

My text document looks like this:

> 1----Polyline1----0.567
>
> ----0.837
>
> 2----Polyline2----0.928
>
> ----0.253

^^^Those are spaces, not dashes

Comment: Do x and s2 have an endline character at the end of them? Were they read from a string that didn't have endlines removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you forgot to strip the newlines from `x` and `x2` after reading them.

Also, ␣ and ␢.

Comment: I don't think they have newlines after them, but if they did how would I strip them?

Comment: @user1191849: To move from "don't think" to "do know", do `print repr(x), repr(x2)`